# corodova で作成したアプリにFCMにてiOSにプッシュ通知をするとAppleDeliveryError:BAD_REQUEST_TOPIC_DISALLOWEDになる。

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase, push-notification

Androidには正常に通知されるのですが、iOSでは下記のエラーが発生します。
他に作成したアプリでは同じ手順でうまく動作しており悩んでおります。

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

```
{
    "multicast_id": 1211587257935608137,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [{
        "error": "InvalidParameters: AppleDeliveryError:BAD_REQUEST_TOPIC_DISALLOWED"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。バンドルID を jp.co.xxx.xxx のように４つの文字列で構成したのですが、jp.xxx.xxx の３つの文字列にしたところうまく動作しました。